# Can't Parse JSON data from URL

Tags: android, json

I'm having trouble getting this to display correctly in my app. It tells me it cannot parse the JSON like this. Here is the code to do so:

```
private class SearchActivity2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String result = "";
        String s = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = null;
        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //show.setText(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        HttpGet httpget = null;
        try {
            httpget = new HttpGet("http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=" + search);
            //System.out.println("http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=" + search);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            //show.setText(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //show.setText(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //show.setText(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            //show.setText(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = s +
                        "Title : " + json.getString("title") + "\n" +
                        "Rating : " + json.getString("rating") + "\n";
            }

            //show.setText(s);
            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
        }

        return s;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        showSearch.setText(s);
    }
}
```

For now, I'm just trying to display the Title and Rating from that website. In this case it would be http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q= + whatever the user types in. So, http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=The+Incredible+Hulk would work, or something to that nature.

Here is the logcat error: 04-24 14:34:56.009  11886-12595/com.android.movies E/log_tag﹕

> Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"series":0,"imdbid":"tt3628580","genres":"Animation,Comedy","imdburl":"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3628580/","votes":"126","runtime":"21min","country":"n/a","stv":1,"languages":"English","title":"The
>   Most Interesting Man in the
>   World","cacheExpiry":1398972896,"year":"132014","usascreens":0,"rating":"6.9","ukscreens":0}
>   of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: i think that the result is not an array at all ... maybe because before i tried to use json i read about it ...

Answer (score 0):

Why go through all that when you can just do it in these simple steps.

**Step 1 :**  Establish connection and get the json.

```
public String loadJSON(String someURL) {

        String json = null;
        HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(someURL);

        try {

            HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
            StatusLine statusline = mHttpResponse.getStatusLine();
            int statuscode = statusline.getStatusCode();
            if (statuscode != 200) {

                return null;

            }
            InputStream jsonStream = mHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                builder.append(line);

            }

            json = builder.toString();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
        mHttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return json;

    }
```

**Next Step:** Use that method to load the json like this:

**NOTE:** You can use the above method to connect to any url and get the json.

```
public void ParseJSON(String URL){

        try{

            JSONObject mainJSONObject = new JSONObject(loadJSON(URL));
            //If want just that particular block of information.
            /*String getTitle = mainJSONObject.getString("title");
            String Country = mainJSONObject.getString("country");*/


            for(int i = 0;i<mainJSONObject.length();i++){//If you want all the data from the json.

                String getTitle = mainJSONObject.getString("title");
                String Country = mainJSONObject.getString("country");
                //Rest you will figure it out.


            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

**Next Step :** Use AsyncTask to load the stuff in background.

```
public class someTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        Context context;
        String URL;

        public someTask(Context context, String someURL){

            super();
            this.context = context;
            this.URL = someURL;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading files...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ParseJSON(URL);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**Last Step :** Just execute the task in the onCreate() like this:

new someTask(context,your_url_you_want_to_execute).execute();

Hope this solution is easy and helps you in your prob. Lemme know it that works.Good Luck ..:)

Comment: There may be some adjustments in the code you want to make.. Again, this is just to break down the problem.

Comment: Seems like it will work, but I need to set the result of the parse to a TextView.

Comment: Before the pDialog.dismiss(); just set your textview in the onPostExecute() like : your_text_view.setText(Your Json value..i.e. The string where you are getting the value);